# How to delete second element from pairs in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get:

[(1,2),(3,4),(4,5)] = [1,3,4]

My attemp:

```
fun2 :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
fun2 [] = []
fun2 ((a,b):ts) = **drop b**:fun2 ts  --have problem here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` with [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst):

```
fun2 :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
fun2 = map fst
```

or use pattern matching, like you already did:

```
fun2 :: [(a, b)] -> [a]
fun2 [] = []
fun2 ((a, _):ts) = a : fun2 ts
```